# Do the flags get called when I make this program?

Tags: c++, makefile

I recently got feedback that my Makefile doesn't call the required flags. This is a snippet of my Makefile.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall

all: testFacility testCode testRunway testSiteNumber airport distance

testFacility: testFacility.cpp Facility.o gcdistance.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^
```

Does the flag "-Wall" get called when I type Make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it needs to be referenced directly:

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

You probably want to define something to compile all those `.cpp` files too:

```
%.o: %.cpp 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

testFacility: testFacility.o Facility.o gcdistance.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```